# R X13binary missing in docker build

Tags: r, docker, conda

I have a docker file where i'm trying to install the R seasonal library:

```sh
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.12 # Debian

. . .

# Install packages not on conda
RUN conda activate r_env && \
    R -e "install.packages(c('RUnit', 'seasonal'), dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.case.edu')"
```

Everything looks like it installs correctly, however when I get into the container and run `library(seasonal)` I get the error:

```
> library(seasonal)
The binaries provided by 'x13binary' do not work on this
machine. To get more information, run:
  x13binary::checkX13binary()

> x13binary::checkX13binary()
Error in x13binary::checkX13binary() : X-13 binary file not found
```

After some googling it looks like I can manually set the path for the binary and a findutil shows that the binary exists on the machine:

```sh
(r_env) root@89c7265d9316:/# find / -name "*x13*"
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/help/x13binary.rdx
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/help/x13binary.rdb
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/html/x13path.html
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/html/x13binary-package.html
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/bin/x13ashtml.exe
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary.rdx
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary.rdb
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary
/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/conda-meta/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0.json
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/help/x13binary.rdx
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/help/x13binary.rdb
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/html/x13path.html
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/html/x13binary-package.html
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/bin/x13ashtml.exe
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary.rdx
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary.rdb
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0/lib/R/library/x13binary/R/x13binary
/opt/conda/pkgs/r-x13binary-1.1.39_2-r36h6115d3f_0.tar.bz2
```

However no matter whatever I set the path to be, the library still throws errors on where the actual path is:

```
(r_env) root@89c7265d9316:/# export X13_PATH=/opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary
(r_env) root@89c7265d9316:/# R -e "library(seasonal)"

The system variable 'X13_PATH' has been manually set to:
  /opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary
Since version 1.2, 'seasonal' relies on the 'x13binary'
package and does not require 'X13_PATH' to be set anymore.
Only set 'X13_PATH' manually if you intend to use your own
binaries. See ?seasonal for details.
Binary executable file /opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/x13as or /opt/conda/envs/arimaApiR/lib/R/library/x13binary/x13ashtml not found.
See ?seasonal for details.
```

I feel like I'm running in circles.  Has anyone had luck running this inside a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've prepared my own container but I didn't use continuumio/miniconda since I don't know how it works inside.

This is the Dockerfile I've prepared:

```
FROM r-base:3.6.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages('RUnit', dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.case.edu')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('x13binary', dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.case.edu')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('seasonal', dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.case.edu')"

CMD [ "bash" ]
```

If I run your test commands, I receive this:

```
> library(seasonal)
> x13binary::
x13binary::checkX13binary     x13binary::supportedPlatform  x13binary::x13path            
> x13binary::checkX13binary
x13binary::checkX13binary
> x13binary::checkX13binary()
x13binary is working properly
>
```

NOTE: the Dockerfile can be improve, e.g. you can put together the packages `c(RUnit, x13binary, seasonal)` and you can remove the apt cache after installing the package but I just wanted to run a test to see if it'd work.

Comment: Bah thanks!  It looks like the problem is with conda, not docker exactly.  I've already ran `conda install -c r r-x13binary`, however installing it through cran fixes it.

Comment: have you tried to add `RUN R -e "install.packages('x13binary', dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.case.edu')"` in your Dockerfile? It looks like your R was complaining that we you were trying to use binary directly.

Comment: Sorry my last comment wasn't clear, yeah I just removed the conda install of x13 and used R to install it through cran.